# What are some effective ways to pass variables between machines?

Tags: python, database, scalability

This is bit of a general question but I wanted to know some different approaches to sharing data between machines.

Basically I have a process that generates large reference table(often over 10gig python dict) and then other machines run independent proceses but reference that table. The dict does not change once its created and all the other machines simply refer to it to do their work.  I'm leaning towards storing all this in a database and then having all the servers query the server to get that data.  I just suspect it might having multiple 10gig+ queries at the same time may not be the best way to do it. I have thought about a flat file or passing it over using a distribution tool.

Is there any other ways to share this python dict among several machines(general approaches are fine but I'm using python so any library suggestion would work also)?

Comment: Do you want a single copy of the dictionary which is shared by all of them, or for each to have a local copy of the dictionary? If you want each machine to have its own copy, [Python's cPickle](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html#module-cPickle) is a good way to pass things around.

Comment: I suppose we need more info about how the archive is structured and accessed.

You mention the risk of having 10+gig queries which is already a bit strange. 
Also, is this "static"? I.e. the main data set changes slowly or not at all? Do the clients update it, or is it read-only?

Comment: I'm sorry I should have mentioned that, the dict is only referenced so once its created it does not change.

Comment: Actually, you got me thinking, what would the difference in the solution be if it wasn't static? For this process it is static for sure, but now you got me thinking of different approaches to sorting the table I am creating(right now its just multiprocessed and stored as a local variable)

Comment: If the data is static, it may make sense replicating it on every "node". If you really have to move around gigabytes of stuff, having it on the same machine serving it will reduce latency. On the other hand, if the dictionary has to be "editable" by nodes, keeping everything in sync would make things much more complicated, so it would be better having a single centralized copy (and put some caching layer between the central dictionary and the clients).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, yes, it would make sense to store it in some kind of shared datastore. Depending on your exact needs, you may find it preferable to store the data in some kind of nosql-type storage. For example redis ( http://redis.io ) is pretty reasonable, and supports various datastructures, including hashtables.